# How to make a number to be from a given set in OCL?

Tags: uml, ocl

There's a class 'Grade' with its 'value' atrribute set to Real and my question is how to write in OCL this condition:

> The grade is a number from a set {2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
inv:Set{2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}->includes(self.value)
```

(admittedly I'm no OCL professional)